# How do I get Django to display what, I want in database

Tags: html, django, database, django-templates, django-views

Thanks for helping. I'm sorry I'm bad at programming.

Ok, I'm trying to take data out my database (SQLite 3) and display all at once.

This my code for views

```
def index(request):
tank = tank_system.objects.all()
args = {'tank':tank}
return render(request,'FrounterWeb/includes.html',args)
```

and here are my HTML that place

```
{% block content %}
<div class ="table-responsive-sm">
        <!-- tables tiles -->
  <table class ="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm">
  <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>EC</th>
        <th>pH</th>
        <th>Tank level</th>
        <th>room temptures</th>
        <th>Water temptrure</th>
  </tr>
      {% for tank_system in tank %}
      <tr>
          <td>time</td>
    <td>{{tank.EC}}</td>
    <td>{{tank.PH}}</td>
    <td>{{tank.WaterLevel}} lites</td>
          <td>{{tank.TempRoom}} C</td>
          <td>{{tank.TempWater}} C</td>
      </tr>

                {%endfor%}
  </table>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

the end result  [objects.all() result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp2Rq.png)

But if I would to modified to with `objects.get(id=x)`

Here modified views;

```
    def index(request):
        tank = tank_system.objects.get(id=1)
        args = {'tank':tank}
        return render(request,'FrounterWeb/includes.html',args)

and adjustment made in HTML;

{% block content %}
<div class ="table-responsive-sm">
        <!-- tables tiles -->
  <table class ="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm">
  <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>EC</th>
        <th>pH</th>
        <th>Tank level</th>
        <th>room temptures</th>
        <th>Water temptrure</th>
  </tr>

      <tr>
          <td>time</td>
    <td>{{tank.EC}}</td>
    <td>{{tank.PH}}</td>
    <td>{{tank.WaterLevel}} lites</td>
          <td>{{tank.TempRoom}} C</td>
          <td>{{tank.TempWater}} C</td>
      </tr>


  </table>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and end result for this is [objects.get(id=) result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lev4x.png)

I guarantee that the database pass jQuery data/object into my html, but now I'm stumped on how to fix this....

please help it should be simply fix

Comment: What is your question? What is wrong in those screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the for loop in your template. You're using a loop variable called `tank_system`, but then referring to a non-existent variable called `tank` when you output each attribute.

Using the correct variable name of `tank_system` should resolve, e.g.

```
{% for tank_system in tank %}
<tr>
    <td>time</td>
    <td>{{tank_system.EC}}</td>
    <td>{{tank_system.PH}}</td>
    <td>{{tank_system.WaterLevel}} lites</td>
    <td>{{tank_system.TempRoom}} C</td>
    <td>{{tank_system.TempWater}} C</td>
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: I guess this is the answer, although OP hasn't actually said what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, Daniel that was the answer, I was actually printing out my list, I want the print out my object. That the problem. Thank you, Daniel and Will; I can't thank you enough.